# Porting inversion of 1000x1000 matrix of complex numbers from Matlab to C++

Tags: c++, matlab, matrix, porting

Matlab code:

```
invD = inv(D);
Dew=2*invD-E;
```

D is 1000x1000 matrix of complex numbers. It inverts in 0,5 sec or less.

I tried several ways of porting this code to C++, using different approaches, but it is always slower than 10 seconds. What am I doing wrong? How possibly Matlab optimizes that code?

I did't write this matlab code, I just have to port it. Sorry, I'm much better in coding that in math.

Comment: Matlab has highly optimized code that uses proper data structures, multithreading and CPU caches in an optimal way—and I wouldn't be surprised if it used different code for different CPUs to get advantage. That's why it's so fast.

Comment: That is a really hard problem. Lots of thought from very clever people has gone into the code that is part of MATLAB. There is no chance that you as a single developer with little experience will come close to MATLAB's performance for operations like this. You should use available C++ libraries for that job.

Comment: I've tried Eigen library. The inversion is still very slow. Or maybe I'm doing something wrong...

Comment: Maybe you should tell us more about your use case. What is it for? Why do you need it in C++? Lapack for example can be good, but it's not really easy to use.

Comment: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/23195601/matlab.m
It's a physics simulation in Matlab. My job is to port it to Qt. I just have to do it. I don't really understand that Matlab code, but I ported 90% of it to C++ without any problem. The part with inverting the matrix made my task tricky.

Comment: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/23195601/matlab.JPG

Comment: Well, you can call matlab from C++, but it does seem strange that Eigen should be so much slower than Matlab. However, I also think there's something fishy with that Matlab file you've provided. My Matlab is a bit rusty, but somehow this seems weird. In particular, the loop at the bottom is only run once, so all the hard work that went into inverting never shows up on the plot.

Comment: 1. I removed "return;" and "T=1", that was debug, sorry.
2. It does, after every loop Psi matrix is multiplied by Dew matrix and Dew is based on inversion of D. I also find it magic. The link is the same.

Comment: And I really appreciate that you found time for looking into that code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am fairly sure you are using `Eigen` incorrectly. I tried inverting a random 1000x1000 matrix with octave (free alternative to MATLAB, probably slightly less optimized) and with the following Eigen code. Octave takes about 1s, Eigen about 1.5s (I'm using `boost::timer` instead of your timing solution, but only because it's less of a hassle):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <boost/timer/timer.hpp>

using Eigen::MatrixXcd;

int main() {
    MatrixXcd m,mi;
  {
    boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer t;
    m = MatrixXcd::Random(1000,1000);
  }
  {
    boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer t;
    mi = m.inverse();
  }
    std::cout << mi(4,4) << std::endl;
}
```

The first possible culprit I can think of are compiler options. Did you compile your C++ code with `-O2` at least?

There is still a possibility that your matrices have a special structure, so that numerical considerations make the Eigen algorithm slower in your particular case, but I would look elsewhere for the problem before considering that.

Comment: It was the case of optimization... I'm really sorry for weasting your time. Now it's 5 s.

Comment: Terrific work, us2012.  I voted you up; I'd do it again if I could.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than re-invent the wheel you can just use [boost::ublas](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm) and follow [these instructions](http://www.crystalclearsoftware.com/cgi-bin/boost_wiki/wiki.pl?LU_Matrix_Inversion).

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear to me what you're doing with that inverse.  My first reaction is that most people don't invert matricies.  For example, LU decomposition is far more efficient and stable solver than full inversion.

I'd suggest finding a [linear algebra library written in C++](http://math.nist.gov/lapack++/).  Other people that far better than you at both math and programming have solved this problem.  User their code; don't write your own.

I'd also recommend looking at [CUDA](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/CUDA/training/GTC_Express_Sarah_Tariq_June2011.pdf) if you have a GPU.

1000x1000 isn't a stunningly large matrix.  Solving problems with millions of degrees of freedom is not unheard of.

Comment: I've tried Eigen library, because it's header only and that makes a few things easier in my projects. It also supports std::complex. It inverts this matrix in 20 seconds or more. Will Lapack invert it much faster?

Comment: If you want eigenvalues, maybe you should try another algorithm.